# Saving H2o data frame

Tags: r, h2o

I am working with 10GB training data frame. I use H2o library for faster computation. Each time I load the dataset, I should convert the data frame into H2o object which is taking so much time. Is there a way to store the converted H2o object ? (so that i can skip the as.H2o(trainingset) step each time I make trails on building models )

Comment: `my_object<-as.h2o(my_training)`?

Comment: Can you provide an example? And 10GB is rather large object anyway, I would not expect to happen very quickly.

Answer (score 5):

After the first transformation with `as.h2o(trainingset)` you can export / save the file to disk and later import it again.

```
my_h2o_training_file <- as.h2o(trainingset)
path <- "whatever/my/path/is"
h2o.exportFile(my_h2o_training_file , path = path)
```

And when you want to load it use either `h2o.importFile` or `h2o.importFolder`. See the function help for correct usage.

Or save the file as csv / txt before you transform it with `as.h2o` and load it directly into h2o with one of the above functions.

Comment: For Python: `h2o.export_file(df, 'C:\\PATH\\TO\\FILE')`.

Answer (score 4):

`as.h2o(d)` works like this (even when client and server are the same machine):

1. In R, export `d` to a csv file in a temp location
2. Call `h2o.uploadFile()` which does an HTTP POST to the server, then a single-threaded import.
3. Returns the handle from that import
4. Deletes the temp csv file it made.

Instead, prepare your data in advance somewhere(*), then use `h2o.importFile()` (See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.importFile.html). This saves messing around with the local file, and it can also do a parallelized read and import.

*: For speediest results, the "somewhere" should be as close to the server as possible. For it to work at all, the "somewhere" has to be somewhere the *server* can see. If client and server are the same machine, then that is automatic. At the other extreme, if your server is a cluster of machines in an AWS data centre on another continent, then putting the data into S3 works well. You can also put it on HDFS, or on a web server.

See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/importing-data.html for some examples in both R and Python.